# Trembling Hand Perfect Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

[image]

I am looking to find all pure strategies Trembling Hand Perfect Equilibrium. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Please, mark the answer as accepted if it correctly answers your question or provide a reason for not doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two results hold for the notion of normal-form trembling-hand perfect (THP) equilibrium.

Corollary: in a THP equilibrium, no weakly dominated pure strategy can be played with positive probability.

Lemma. In any two-player game, any Nash equilibrium without weakly dominated strategies is THP.

The corollary rules out the Nash equilibrium $(R,F)$. The lemma confirms that the other two Nash equilibria $(T,D)$ and $(B,E)$ are also THP.